# Why is the signleton object named differently from the class in this example?

Tags: scala

I am following Martin Odersky's Functional Programming Principles in Scala Coursera and one thing that I do not understand is why does he make a Singleton object a different name from the class, I thought both should be the same name? Also he tries to make an instance of the new `IntSet`, which cannot happen because it is abstract, but should he not make it inside the main method?

Code:

```
object intsets {
  new IntSet

}
 abstract class IntSet {
   def incl(x: Int): IntSet
   def contains(x: Int): Boolean
 }
```

Comment: are you sure this is the right code? it seems strange

Comment: `object` doesn't have to have same name as class, only companion object must follow that rule. If `intsets` is not a companion object - it can be called in any way.